# How to create a login on a test server without active directory domain?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, authentication, testing

I'm trying to create a login on our test server with:

```sql
CREATE LOGIN [<DOMAIN>\<LOGIN>] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

As opposed to the live server the test server does not have any active directory. So it fails with:

```
Windows NT user or group 'DOMAIN\LOGIN' not found. Check the name again.
```

Worth to be mentioned, that on the test server we use a backup of a database dump from the last release and apply new migrations to this dump. This means, that this error would not occur, if a more recent dump from the live server was used, where the active directory login already exists.

To enable proper testing, we discussed three possible options:

1. Recreate the active directory on the test server: I would like to avoid this, because nobody really wants to administer an additional active directory clone for testing purposes.
2. Use a more recent database dump: The problem here is, that the live server is not ours and we only have restricted access to it. It is possible, but still not the optimal solution in regard to practicability. Also, it would mean, that we would play in migrations to the live server before having tested them on the test server.
3. Alternative SQL syntax: I am aware, that there alternative ways of creating logins, e.g., `CREATE LOGIN <login_name> WITH PASSWORD`. But I could not think of any way, which allows us to create logins depending on which system we are on.

Option 3 is our strong favorite, but we are missing a piece to the puzzle. Anything we are missing here?

Comment: The first option should be to use a local Windows account

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user on your local computer.
And then add this new user to the instance.

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName or your hostName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS;
```